# Why usr/bin/ld is showing wrong path?

Tags: linux, ld

I am trying to install lzo compression but when I configure and make 
following error comes:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/Desktop/open/lzolib/lib/liblzo2.a(lzo1x_1o.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/home/user/Desktop/open/lzolib/lib/liblzo2.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
```

The above error will come cause file is in indeed in different format but if it will go to below path it will work correctly

It has to got to /home/user/Desktop/**open_x86**/lzolib/lib/liblzo2.a

above path

How to reset path of usr/bin/ld ?

Comment: Did you try telling the configure script where it is?

Comment: Try with adding open_X86 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH system variable

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/Desktop/open_x86/lzolib/lib:%LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes i have added the correct path to configure script